# Document Library "Modified By" metadata disappears after 2-3 seconds

Tags: column, metadata

I have a SharePoint Online site with one Document Library and would like to see who last modified files/folders. Once the page loads, all the metadata displays properly but 2-3 seconds later, the whole "Modified By" column metadata just disappears.
I have tried different browsers/networks and the issue persists. 
What could trigger this and how do I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
- there is no custom code anywhere on the site
- I have created a new site within the same site collection and the issue persists even on the new site
EDIT2:
- the issue does not persist when using the "classic experience" theme

Comment: Did you check is there any custom javascript code on your page?

Comment: There is no custom code anywhere on the site. It's as vanilla as it gets.

Comment: Just curious, does this issue occur on other computers? If so does it happen for all users?

Comment: The issue occurs for all users, on mobile as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good practice or not but adding the following code to the Modified By column formatting fixed the issue for me:

{
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField.title"
}